# Gmail TLS hanshake failure in haskell

Tags: haskell, gmail, ssl, handshake

I am trying to write a little script to send an email via gmail.
I can connect to gmail but when I try to hanshake it fails.
Any pointers to get the handshake a go?

Here is the code:

```
import Network.Socket
import Network
import Network.TLS
import Network.TLS.Extra

import Crypto.Random
import Data.CertificateStore -- to remove
import System.Certificate.X509 --to use I think

import System.IO
import Text.Printf

import Control.Monad (forever)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B


main :: IO ()
main = emailGmail2

tListen :: Context -> IO ()
tListen ctx =
    forever $ recvData ctx >>= B.putStrLn

cWrite :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
cWrite h s  = do
    hPrintf h "%s\r\n" s
    printf    "> %s\n" s

cListen :: Handle -> IO () 
cListen h =
    forever $ hGetLine h >>= putStrLn

emailGmail2 = do
    let
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 587
        params = defaultParamsClient
    g <- newGenIO :: IO SystemRandom
    h <- connectTo host (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h LineBuffering
    cWrite h "EHLO"
    cWrite h "STARTTLS"
    --cListen h
    con <- contextNewOnHandle h params g
    handshake con
    tListen con
```

And here's the error:

> HandshakeFailed (Error_Packet_Parsing "Failed reading: invalid header
>   type: 50\nFrom:\theader\n\n")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is partially to do with handling the SMTP protocol. Looking at the RFC for Secure SMTP over TLS [RFC 2487](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2487) there is an example client-server dialogue.

```
S: <waits for connection on TCP port 25>
C: <opens connection>
S: 220 mail.imc.org SMTP service ready
C: EHLO mail.ietf.org
S: 250-mail.imc.org offers a warm hug of welcome
S: 250 STARTTLS
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 Go ahead
C: <starts TLS negotiation>
C & S: <negotiate a TLS session>
C & S: <check result of negotiation>
C: <continues by sending an SMTP command>
. . .
```

In your code you are sending EHLO and STARTTLS, and then immediately beginning the handshake negotiation. I believe what is happening is that the server is still sending some of the 250 and 220 codes above and the TLS library is trying to interpret these as TLS messages which is causing the problem.

Indeed if I open another terminal and listen to port 587 with netcat and change the program to connect to localhost I get the same error if I reply with "250 STARTTLS"

Changing this got the program to work for me:

```
import Network.Socket
import Network
import Network.TLS
import Network.TLS.Extra

import Crypto.Random
import qualified Crypto.Random.AESCtr as RNG
import System.IO
import Text.Printf

import Control.Monad (when)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

ciphers :: [Cipher]
ciphers =
        [ cipher_AES128_SHA1
        , cipher_AES256_SHA1
        , cipher_RC4_128_MD5
        , cipher_RC4_128_SHA1
        ]

main :: IO ()
main = emailGmail2

cWrite :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
cWrite h s  = do
    hPrintf h "%s\r\n" s
    printf    "> %s\n" s

cWaitFor :: Handle -> String -> IO ()
cWaitFor h str = do
    ln <- hGetLine h
    putStrLn ln
    when (not $ str `isPrefixOf` ln) (cWaitFor h str)

emailGmail2 = do
    let
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 587
        params = defaultParamsClient{pCiphers = ciphers}
    g <- RNG.makeSystem
    h <- connectTo host (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h LineBuffering
    cWrite h "EHLO"
    cWaitFor h "250-STARTTLS"
    cWrite h "STARTTLS"
    cWaitFor h "220"
    con <- contextNewOnHandle h params g
    handshake con
    bye con
```

Also note that I needed to add some ciphers from `Network.TLS.Extras` as otherwise I got an Illegal Parameter error. I found the code for this and to add logging from Vincent's tests on the Github [page](https://github.com/vincenthz/hs-tls/blob/master/debug/src/SimpleClient.hs).

Another note: In case you run into more issues I should point out that I used the command line programs gnutls-cli and ssldump to debug the issue with ciphers mentioned above.

Comment: Wow! Welcome to SO, nice start.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at the RF but did not found the error. I will try to make a lib out of it (do I have the skills?) because it is something that should be present by default (my opinion).